# How to cascade selection of a matrix visual's cell into another matrix?

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report page with 2 matrix visuals.

The 1st matrix visual has following columns:

Year|Month|OrderQty|SalesAmt

The 2nd matrix visual has following columns:

Country|City|OrderQty|SalesAmt

There is a slicer visual for Year and Month. Selecting a value filters both the matrix visual.

Assume that Years 2021, 2022 are selected in the slicer.

I have been asked to provide a functionality such that when user clicks on the Month cell value (example June) in the 1st matrix visual, then the 2nd matrix visual should show data for the respective year/month (based on the cell in the 1st matrix visual).

Is this possible in Power BI? If not, then what is the alternative?

Comment: Can you supply a sample .pbix to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Simple question. Can selecting the matrix cells (rows) filter another matrix.

Comment: Yes, of course. That is why I asked for a minimal reproducible example as I'm not sure what problem you're facing.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Someone had turned off the enable interaction setting. If you write this in answer and mark as answer then I will accept the answer.

Comment: Sure. Sometimes it is the simple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure  you have checked that cross-filtering is enabled on the Format->Edit Interactions menu.

[image]